# Not getting full screen details when json data is coming Data is hiding below

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image]

I am getting the json data lengthy and i have to scroll the view to get the buttons below. How Can I make the button display. When I am trying to give scrollview its not working.

Comment: Please post your code so that we can understand your issue

Comment: Can you please share the Layout(XML) code?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZcnfhnEA Here i have pasted the link

Comment: @ChinmayMoharana i have edited my answer. Please review and tell if you got any problem. I am here for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your layout structure. I have resolved your problem by adding Relative layout and by giving fix height to scrollview as your scenario is very clear that you want all buttons visible while only scrolling question's content. So here is your solution just copy and paste this xml into your xml. :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3D996C">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/timer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#3D996C"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/play_timmer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_play">

                </ImageButton>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timmer_value"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/_2_30_30"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="24sp">
                </TextView>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_stop"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_stop">

                </ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_previos_skip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/timer_layout"
            android:weightSum="3">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/previous_page"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3D996C"
                android:text="Previous"
                android:textColor="#FFF">
            </Button>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score_card"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="2/200"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold">

            </TextView>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/skip_page"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3D996C"
                android:text="SKIP"
                android:textColor="#FFF" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/question_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_previos_skip"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/questions_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Question no 1"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold">
            </TextView>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone">
        </ProgressBar>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_below="@+id/question_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/answers_group"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/answer1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ANSWER 1">
                </RadioButton>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/answer2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ANSWER 2">
                </RadioButton>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/answer3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ANSWER 3">
                </RadioButton>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/answer4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ANSWER 4">
                </RadioButton>
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button

            android:id="@+id/submit_and_procced"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="#ed9c28"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="SUBMIT AND PROCEED"
            android:textColor="#6F0606"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
            >
        </Button>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/last_page"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/skipped"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ed9c28"
                    android:text="SKIPPED"
                    android:textColor="#831212"
                    android:textSize="18sp">

                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/answered"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#3D996C"
                    android:text="ANSWERED"
                    android:textColor="#00695C"
                    android:textSize="18sp">
                </Button>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried putting <ScrollView> after <TextView></TextView><ScrollView> not working.

Comment: Can you please share your xml? It would be helpful to understand the exact problem.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZcnfhnEA here i have send the code in pastebin Please have a look

Comment: @ChinmayMoharana i have edited my answer. Please review and tell if you got any problem. I am here for you.

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad Zahab Ahmed Khan its working thanks a lot